# Is it possible to pass HIGH and LOW values as parameter in a function?

Tags: code-optimization

I've created the following function:

```
void runMotor(int _dir, int _step, int wait){
  digitalWrite(_dir, HIGH);
  for (int x = 0; x < 3200; x++) {
    digitalWrite(_step, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(wait);
    digitalWrite(_step, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(wait);
  }
```

In the first line inside the function I used the value `HIGH` as a fixed value. I would like to know if there's a way to pass the values `HIGH` and `LOW` as a parameter in this function. Is it possible?

Or should I just create a new function to rotate my step motor to the other side?

Comment: `HIGH` is just an alias for the number 1. `LOW` is just an alias for the number 0. Anywhere you can use numbers you can use `HIGH` or `LOW` equally. You can even use them in math: `HIGH + HIGH == 2`. The same goes for things like `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, `RISING`, `FALLING`, etc. They are just aliases to numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`digitalWrite` expects the pin and value to be `uint8_t` type. So you can certainly pass LOW or HIGH to functions.

For example:

```c++
void runMotor(int _dir, int _step, int wait, uint8_t value){
  digitalWrite(_dir, value);
```

Comment: What about Analog pins? Are they expected to be uint8_t values as well?

Comment: I meant what about the analogRead() function...

Comment: What do you mean? You don't pass `HIGH` or `LOW` to analogRead. You mean the pin numbers? Yes the pin number is `uint8_t` as well.